# How to use a custom font in pywebview

Tags: html, css, fonts, pywebview

I want to use a custom font in a `pywebview` application, but after adding the CSS, only the fallback font is used. The font files are located in the `/css/fonts` directory, but neither relative or absolute paths would work.

My CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Retro Gaming';
  src: url('fonts/retro_gaming.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/retro_gaming-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/retro_gaming-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.menu {
  font-family: 'Retro Gaming', Courier, monospace;
}
```

My HTML:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p class="menu">This font should be Retro Gaming</p>
  <p>This font should be Courier New</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The messages I see when I start the app are:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 18:13:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 200
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 18:13:11] "GET /fonts/retro_gaming.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 42
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 18:13:11] "GET /fonts/retro_gaming-webfont.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 52
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2020 18:13:11] "GET /fonts/retro_gaming-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 404 51
```

EDIT:
Image with path to font files:

[image: Image with path to font files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I works fine by placing the font files in the same directory where the html is (in my case, `assets`). You can even create subdirectories for the fonts in there.

EDIT: another option is to avoid loading the styles to the window inside the python code and doing it from the HTML directly.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `../` before your location file if your html code in another file and the css too like this `../fonts/retro_gaming.ttf` it worked for me when i did like your path.

Comment: Same 404 results.

Comment: can you give an image for the font file and the path

Comment: Sure, I updated my question with an image.